# How to Get the Max_date or min_date value in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am new to MYSQL, I have a requirement to get the MAX_date() or Min_date() inside the stored procedure. Let us know is there any inbuilt function to get the minimum Date or maximum Date in MYSQL?

Comment: A classic case for RTFM. Before you ask here for help show at least some minimum effort you have done on your side to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MAX() & MIN() functions inside the query in your stored procedure.
Syntax is MAX(your_date).

More info in MySQL reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max